# Fusion Log Viewer not working after Windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, windows-8.1, assemblybinding, fusion-log-viewer

I’ve noticed that after I've upgraded to Windows 8.1, Fusion Logger does not work, in the sense, when my .NET projects run (ASP.NET Website), clicking ‘Refresh’ does not yield anything.
It used to work on Windows 8 perfectly fine, before the upgrade.

I’ve tried the `fuslogvw.exe` in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64`

All to no avail.

Solution which people suggested on other questions on stackoverflow haven't worked, though they were for earlier versions of Windows.
I’ve tried running as administrator.
I’ve created the ‘Forcelog’ and ‘LogResourceBinds 'Dwords' with value '1' in the Fusion registry entry as well, all to no avail.

It really makes things hard as I use it extensively for debugging purposes when developing.
Has anyone else faced this, or know of a possible resolution?

Note: I might add. I'm in the process of upgrading my projects from MVC 3 to 4, and use Fusion Log Viewer to sort out incorrect assembly binds. Could it be something to do with MVC 4?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing log bindings from nuget.exe, but not from devenv.exe. I'm getting binding failures when running some of my tests, but they are never logged. Makes me think that Windows is catching the exceptions from VS and consuming them somewhere.